# Traspaso de código PHP a Python & Django

Tags: php, python, django

Tengo algunos problemas al cambiar este código de PHP a Python & Django.
Este el código de php es de un test de velocidad:
https://github.com/adolfintel/speedtest

Esto es el resultado del traspaso que hice pero no me sale del todo bien.

**modelo.py**
from django.db import models

```
class Speedtest(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_created=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ua = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    dl = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    ping = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    jitter = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    lon = models.CharField(max_length=5000,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.ip)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'speedtest'
        verbose_name = 'speedtes'
        verbose_name_plural = 'speedtes'
```

**views.py**

```
import math
import sys
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
from requests import get
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json


def getIP(request):
    data = {}
    if request.GET['isp']:
        isp = ""
        ip  = ""
        try:
            ip = get_client_ip(request)
            url = "https://ipinfo.io/json"
            details = get(url).json()
            isp += details["org"] if "loc" in details else "Unknown ISP"
            isp += ", " + details["country"] if "country" in details else ""
            clientLoc = details["loc"] if "loc" in details else ""
            if request.GET['distance']:
                if clientLoc:
                    details = get("https://ipinfo.io/json").json()
                    serverLoc = details['loc'] if "loc" in details else ""
                    if serverLoc:
                        clientLoc = clientLoc.split(",")
                        serverLoc = serverLoc.split(",")
                        dist = distance(float(clientLoc[0]), float(clientLoc[1]), float(serverLoc[0]),
                                        float(serverLoc[1]))
                        if request.GET['distance'] == "mi":
                            dist /= 1.609344
                            dist = round(dist, -1)
                            dist = "<15" if (dist < 15) else ""
                            isp += " (" + dist + " mi)"
                        elif request.GET['distance'] == "km":
                            dist = "<20" if (dist < 20) else ""
                            isp += " (" + dist + " km)"
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            isp = "Unknown ISP"
        data = [ip + " - " + isp]
        print(data)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')


def empty(request):
    data = {
        "HTTP/1.1 200": "OK",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0",
        "Cache-Control": "post-check=0,pre-check=0, false",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive"
    }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")


def distance(latitudeFrom, longitudeFrom, latitudeTo, longitudeTo):
    rad = math.pi / 180
    theta = longitudeFrom - longitudeTo
    dist = math.sin(latitudeFrom * rad) * math.sin(latitudeTo * rad) + math.cos(latitudeFrom * rad) * math.cos(
        latitudeTo * rad) * math.cos(theta * rad)
    return math.acos(dist) / rad * 60 * 1.853


def get_client_ip(request):
    url = "https://ipinfo.io/json"
    details = get(url).json()
    return details['ip']


from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.gzip import *
from django.views.decorators.vary import *
@never_cache
@gzip_page
@vary_on_headers
@vary_on_cookie

def garbage(request):
    data = os.urandom(1048576)
    chunks = int(request.GET['ckSize']) if request.GET['ckSize'] else 4
    if chunks is None:
        chunks = 4
    if chunks > 100:
        chunks = 100
    for x in range(0, chunks):
        print(data)
        sys.stdout.flush()


def test_velocity(request):
    data = {
        'titulo': 'Test de velocidad'
    }
    return render(request, 'speed/speed.html', data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from .views import getIP, garbage, test_velocity, empty

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^getIP$', getIP, name="getIP"),
    url(r'^garbage$',garbage, name="garbage"),
    url(r'^empty$',empty, name="empty"),
    url(r'^$',test_velocity, name="test_velocity"),
]
```

Al hacer pruebas de test de velocidad no me da las valores que deberían ser. Sobretodo en esta page PHP no entiendo unas cosas de los header para el traspaso. https://github.com/adolfintel/speedtest/blob/master/garbage.php